# JavaFX GridPane contains non defined spacing

Tags: javafx, imageview, label, gridpane

Iam trying to add some `Labels` to a `GridPane`.
Those `Labels` contain ImageViews which contain some `Images`.

My images are `.png`-images and are 50 x 50 pixels big.

If my `GridPane` is getting to big to display it on my screen, I want to resize my Images. Iam trying this with the methods `setFitWidth` and `setFitHeight`.

Snipped:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {        
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    
    int ySize = 5;
    int xSize = 5;
    
    int imageSize = 25;
    
    for(int i=0 ; i<ySize ; i++) {
        for(int j=0 ; j<xSize ; j++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("path.png")));
            imageView.setFitWidth(imageSize);
            imageView.setFitHeight(imageSize);
            Label label = new Label();
            label.setGraphic(imageView);        
            gridPane.add(label, i, j);
        }
    }
    
    stage.setScene(new Scene(gridPane));
    
    stage.show();
}
```

The output looks fine:

[image]

However, if `imageSize` is getting to small, for example `10`, a horicontal spacing appears between the rows:

[image]

Is there any way to remove this? I tried to set the label sizes max-properties:

```
label.setMaxHeight(imageSize);
label.setMaxWidth(imageSize);
```

with no effect.

Is there any way to remove the spacing? Is it because the images are .png's?
Thank you

Comment: Why are you using `Label`s at all? You're not using it except for wrapping the `ImageView` which doesn't seem to make much sense here...

Comment: What would be a better approach?

Comment: Simply adding the `ImageView`s themselves, unless you're using `Label`s for a particular reason (which you should explain).

Comment: Wow thanks no idea why I did that. It actually solves my problem. Thank you

Comment: Probably was using labels as wrappers since this was the approach in java swing Iif I remember correctly.. thanks anyway. But do you know why this actually made problems?